# Ruby printing line numbers

Tags: ruby, line, whitespace

I'm trying to check a file line by line for starting white space. I want all the lines to start with space or a tab not both. If there is a line that starts with space and anthers line that starts with tab in the file the code below is going to print warning, but on top of that I want to print 2 lines one that starts with space and one that starts with a tab just to show the user, and Im stuck on how to get the line numbers and stuff. Help!! My code looks like this so far.

```
    file= File.read("file_tobe_checked")
    tabs = spaces = false
    file.each do |line|

    line =~ /^\t/ and tabs = true
    line =~ /^ / and spaces = true  

    if spaces and tabs
    STDERR <<  "The white spaces at the beginning of each line are not consistent.\n"

    end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a number of special variables, one of which is `$.` which is the currently read line's number.

You can also use IO's [`lineno`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-lineno) method.

```
IO.lineno

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ios.lineno    -> integer

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Returns the current line number in ios.  The stream must be opened for
reading. lineno counts the number of times #gets is called rather than the
number of newlines encountered.  The two values will differ if #gets is called
with a separator other than newline.

Methods that use $/ like #each, #lines and #readline will also increment
lineno.

See also the $. variable.

  f = File.new("testfile")
  f.lineno   #=> 0
  f.gets     #=> "This is line one\n"
  f.lineno   #=> 1
  f.gets     #=> "This is line two\n"
  f.lineno   #=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the first line number which starts with each as your predicate if there is such a line:

```
file= File.read("file_tobe_checked")
tabs = spaces = nil
line_no = 1
file.each do |line|
  tabs ||= line_no if line =~ /^\t/
  spaces ||= line_no if line =~ /^ /  
  line_no += 1

  if spaces && tabs
    STDERR <<  "The white spaces at the beginning of each line are not consistent.\n"
    STDERR << "Tab line: #{tabs}"
    STDERR << "Space line: #{spaces}"
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to print the line number instead of the content of the line. I tried using $. but it isnt doing what I expected it to do.